best way to migrate a single redis database to new instance due to global eviction policy
I've used redis before but have encountered a sticky situation. We have a redis server with 6 databases. We've maxed out our maxmemory and it's a hodpepodge of applications on this single instance. One of our applications which has logic where it should not EVER evict a key from a specific database (lets say it's db4). I don't believe you can tell Redis to have a policy like don't ever evict from this db, can you?
I could see two solutions but have questions on both:

create a replica of db4 that has sufficient memory so that keys in the replica will never evict. Is there a way to prevent eviction in this new db? Once caught up, point app to new redis instance and make replica standalone. Would that work?
stop writes to redis instnace; dump all the databases via SAVE (can't save a single database) and bring up in new instance, delete out the other databases and point app to this new redis instance.

Any other suggested migration strategies? A rewrite is not optional unfortunately.

Eviction policy is for the server, not the database. So you need to extract that database to a stand-alone instance.
REPLICAOF is also for the entire instance and not a single database. It replicates all the databases.
Given those facts, I would do the following:

Set up a new instance of Redis on a new server with the eviction policy of noevection.
Make that new instance a replica of the existing one using REPLICAOF.
Wait until replication is mostly completed.
Point the application at the new instance of Redis.
Wait for any stragglers to replicate.
Turn off replication for the new instance using REPLICAOF NO ONE.
Delete the other databases on the new instance using SELECT and FLUSHDB.
Delete the migrated database from the existing instance the same way.

And, Bob's your uncle!
